# What is a type mismatch error mean when assigning onreadystatechange?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, types

What is a JavaScript type mismatch error?

And what are the likely causes?

I can't include all the code, but here is the line that gets the error.

```
xmlObject.onreadystatechange = null;
```

Comment: @Grae are you using ajax

Comment: It mostly focused on other languages

Comment: @mgraph Yes. It is setting the onreadystatechange attribute of an an obkject created by ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')

Comment: @Grae can you provide the script of you're ajax request

Comment: Usually caused by a type mis-match: using one type where another was expected. See [this quirks mode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/xmlhttp_notes_a_1.html) and see if it helps.

Comment: @mgraph How did you know it was AJAX

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error because `xmlObject.onreadystatechange` expects a function, but you are assigning `null` to it. This should fix it:

```
xmlObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // handle the readystatechange event here
}
```

Comment: Why could be the reason this only happens sometimes?

Comment: Hi,      `var x=document.getElementById("stMM1");var option=document.createElement("option");option.text="BATCH";option.value="BATCH";x.add(option,x.options[2]);` ..I run this code using chrome, mozilla, ie9 and it runs successfully. But this code gives an error "Type mismatch" for x.add() row when I use ie9(compatibility view). How to solve it?

Comment: @kamal Try `insertBefore` instead of `add`. If that doesn't work, I believe you should [ask a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).